# "assume to the contrary" vs "assume on the contrary"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I find that when proving a theorem by the method of contradiction, some authors start by saying "assume to the contrary" while some use "assume on the contrary". According to this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70484/to-on-the-contrary-in-these-sentences-is-the-difference-very-slight?newreg=eb8613a1417c422983a108fd128b7320), it seems that "to the contrary" and "on the contrary" have subtle differences. So my question is which one should I use, "assume to the contrary" or "assume on the contrary"?

Below is an example.

> **Theorem.** A is equal to B.
>
> *Proof*: Assume on/to the contrary that A does not equal B. ...

Comment: Can you give the full sentence you want to use it in?

Comment: I'd probably go with just "Assume that A does not equal..."   But forced to include the *contrary* I'd use "Assume the contrary- "